# ClassMethod Attribute in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Will like to get some advice on being able to decorate a WebApi controller class and method.

- Is it possible to add a "method attribute" at class level (instead of method level)?
- How do I add an attribute that take in an enum as parameter? E.g. [AuthorisedRoles(Roles.Developer, Roles.Testers, Roles.PM)]

Thanks in advance for any directions.

Comment: These questions have little to do with WebApi or your question are too vague that they are not easily understood. You should google how to write/create custom in C#. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20write%20custom%20attribute%20in%20c%23

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (not tested):

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    //[Authorize(Roles = "dev, user")]
    [EnumRolesAuthorise(UserRoles.Developer, UserRoles.Testers, UserRoles.PM)]
    public string Get()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class EnumRolesAuthoriseAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public EnumRolesAuthoriseAttribute(params UserRoles[] roles)
    {
        Roles = string.Join(",", roles.Select(r => Enum.GetName(typeof (UserRoles), r)));
    }
}

public enum UserRoles
{
    Developer,
    Testers,
    PM
}
```

I believe you could apply `[EnumRolesAuthorise]` to the controller just as easily as the action just like you would with `[Authorize]`.